# Struggling with Pumping Lemma application

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I have studied Pumping Lemma carefully and have solved many exercises about it but I can't get an idea on how to solve this one: can anyone help me?

Let L = { w#x | x is a substring of w }. Prove that L is not regular.

I have tried setting the Pumping length to |w| and to |x| but I just don't find words that are not in L..

Thx in advance

Comment: What is # in the language? Does it belong to language L?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Note that you don't get to "set" the Pumping length!

Comment: @AlwynMathew andy doesn't give the alphabet; I'd guess that $L \in \{0,1,\#\}$ and $x,w \in \{0,1\}^*$ are reasonable assumptions. "#" is a separator.

Comment: Hint: The Pumping lemma does not characterise REG! It's perfectly possible that a non-regular language *has* the Pumping property. Try [another method](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)! (In fact, I think this one has if we assume a binary alphabet. For larger alphabets, set $w=x$ to a "long" square-free word.)